# Find third vertex of triangle on the Cartesian plane

Tags: triangles

I have a triangle on the cartesian plane where I know the following:
$$
A = (x_1,y_1),
 B = (x_2,y_2),
  C = (x_3,y_3)
$$

I want to find the possible locations for $C$.

I know the location of $A$ and $B$.

I know that I want the angle $ABC$ will be $90^{\mkern1mu\mathrm{o}}$.

and for narrowing the search down, I know that if:
$$
AB = x
$$
then:

$$
AC = 2x
$$
[example triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F05F7.png)

Comment: If $AB$ is the hypotenuse of the rectangle triangle $ACB$ it is impossible that $AB=AC/2$.

Comment: Try https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158679/how-to-calculate-coordinates-of-third-point-in-a-triangle-2d-knowing-2-points or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2156851/calculate-the-coordinates-of-the-third-vertex-of-triangle-given-the-other-two-an

Answer (score 0):

There can be no solution: if $\widehat{ACB}$ is a right angle, C is on the circle with diameter $AB$, and if $AC=2AB$, it is on the circle with centre $A$ and radius $2AB$. These two circles have  no intersection.

Comment: you're right, will edit the question.